# Sending a specific SCSI command to a SCSI device in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scsi

Is it possible to do some Inquiry requests to SCSI driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible from userland.

> By design, Mac OS X does not allow applications to send SCSI or ATA
>   commands to storage devices unless the application developer also
>   provides an in-kernel device driver that supports the commands. The
>   SCSI Architecture Model family allows only one logical unit driver to
>   control a device at a time and provides in-kernel logical unit drivers
>   for storage devices (as listed in “SCSI Architecture Model Family
>   Device Support”). Similarly, the ATA family does not allow
>   applications to send ATA commands directly to ATA or SATA (Serial ATA)
>   devices.

From here
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWithSAM/WWS_SAMDevInt/WWS_SAM_DevInt.html

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not entirely correct.

If the device is not a block disk device but, for instance, a tape drive, and therefore is not driven by a macOS driver by default, then one can talk to it using the functions available in `<IOKit/scsi/SCSITaskLib.h>`, from a userland application. See the "SCSITaskDeviceInterface" section in [Apple's SCSI docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WorkingWithSAM/WWS_SAMDevInt/WWS_SAM_DevInt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000387-BCIJHCIC).